# .Net Socket class error codes

Tags: c++, .net, sockets, winapi

I have been researching both the C++ (or Windows API) method for creating a `socket`, and the .Net method for creating a `socket`. My concern is whether the same error codes that are available in Windows sockets are also available in the .Net `Socket` class. I have looked at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668%28VS.85%29.aspx) on "Windows Sockets Error Codes" and also [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketerror(v=vs.100).aspx), which describes the error codes for the .Net `Socket` class.

After looking at both of the above pages, it seems that the .Net `Socket` class provides just as much in regards to `socket` error reporting as the Windows API. I would prefer to use .Net to implement a `Socket` due to the fact that I feel it would be easier for me as someone who does not have a wide range of knowledge when it comes to C++ and network programming. However, this job requires that I be able to report errors of the same granularity as the Windows API.

I'm trying to be as specific as possible here, but with the information provided, what can you tell me in regards to comparing the two with error codes in mind? With my knowledge, I am thinking that the C# `Socket` class is just as strong in this aspect as the Windows API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you receive a `SocketException` in .NET the exception has a property called [ErrorCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketexception.errorcode(v=vs.100).aspx) which maps to all of the values you posted in your first link.

So both API's are just as granular in their error reporting. The enum you linked to is just for convince so you don't need to make your own constants for the more popular error codes.

```
const int WSA_E_NO_MORE= 10110;
const int WSAEACCES = 10013;

void Foo()
{
    try
    {
       //...
    }
    catch(SocketException ex)
    {
       // These two lines are equivalent.
       //if(ex.ErrorCode == WSAEACCES)
       if(ex.ErrorCode == SocketError.AccessDenied)
       {
            //Do something special for access denied.
       }
       else if(ex.ErrorCode == WSA_E_NO_MORE)
       {
           //Do something special with the WSA_E_NO_MORE error code
       }
    }
}
```

If you want a easy way to see which enum maps to which error code exactly [the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/SocketErrors.cs,cb4675d5a1a2c847) shows what native constant each enum represents.